# Online PHP/HTML/JS/CSS editor

Tags: php, editor, browser-based

is there any free php code that, once installed, allows you to browse and edit files (with html, javascript, php and css highlight) on the server where it's installed? The aim is to code online, browser based. I've tried http://phpanywhere.net/ that can make this possible, but it is buggy and moreover it requires an external (ftp) access to your server that is quite different (and less secure) that working directly on the server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing is less secure than what you're asking for.

Comment: what do you mean, nsd? it should be username/pwd protected, of course, and one can access that part of the site via https, that is certainly more secure than giving away your ftp credential to a 3rd party site...

Comment: NSD, that depends on how well it's guarded. With a proper username and password and preferably over SSL it's fairly safe.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of reasons that this kind of thing might be a bad idea.

- Security.  It would be very hard to make this sort of thing secure.
- Utility.  A text editor on the web is likely to be about as useful as MS Notepad.  It doesn't have the functionality of a good text editor.  It'll also make it harder to do things like source control etc.

That said, I've seen it done before.  For instance cPanel does it.  Maybe you could look into some free cPanel alternatives like [ISPConfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISPConfig) or [EHCP](http://ehcp.net/).  But I would be very wary of using something from someone you don't trust, for security reasons.  Note that there are a lot of security problems that aren't solved by putting something behind SSL.

Comment: well, i must say that a control panel is a bit overkill given that what i'd like is simply a file manager (create, delete, rename, list) with a syntax-highlight text editor...

Answer (score 1):

I just found PHPAnywhere: http://phpanywhere.net/

It looks pretty impressive, I'll probably check it out myself. You may want to investigate ECCO: http://ecco.sourceforge.net/ -- The benefit here of course being that it's open source and downloadable, which unless I'm reading too much into your question, is really what you're wanting. Apparently it's in Alpha status, but the screenshots suggest it's at least moderately functional.

My search also turned up Mozilla Labs' Bespin, an online HTML editor, but so far I don't really, um, get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a service like this, still work in progress
But I want to achieve a better then phpanywhere service :)
Site is [Devcube.nl](http://www.devcube.nl)